# How to pass a php array with json to jquery function, ajax

Tags: php, ajax, arrays, json, parsing

How to pass my php array to this jquery code ?
i have tried json_encoding but couldnt use it in my jquery function.
my json string looks like this:

```
{"1":{"id":"1","league":"england","team1":"Arsenal","team2":"Chelsea"},"2":{"id":"2","league":"spain","team1":"Deportivo","team2":"Real Madrid"}}
```

**JS:**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var shownIds = new Array();
                setInterval(function(){     
                    $.get('livescore_process.php', function(data){
                        for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                            if($.inArray(data[i]["id"], shownIds) == -1){
                                if(data[i]["league"]=="england"){
                                    $("#eng").append("id: " + data[i]["team1"] + " [ "+data[i]["team1"]+ " - "+data[i]["team1"]+" ]"+ data[i]["team2"] +"<br />");
                                }
                                shownIds.push(data[i]["id"]);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }, 3000);
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: The *very first* link in the Related sidebar is titled [How to pass an array using PHP & Ajax to Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263052/how-to-pass-an-array-using-php-ajax-to-javascript?rq=1). Is it really not applicable to your problem? (Edit: also, since your data is not a real array but an object, it won't have a `length` property.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `$.getJSON` instead of `$.get` and use php `json_encode`:

```
$.getJSON('livescore_process.php', function(data){...
```

however the response data is not an array but a json object, so to handle it you can try:

```
$.each(data, function (index, item) {
    if (item.hasOwnProperty('id')) {
        if (item.league == "england") {
            $("#eng").append("id: " + item.team1 + " [ " + item.team1 + " - " + item.team1 + " ]" + item.team2 + "<br />");
        }
        shownIds.push(item.id);

    }
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arcm111/F8yAT/)