# get array from ajax json with javascript

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I have this code which should convert it's results to json.
I want to get the array with js and print it.

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Contact', 'root', '');
$statement=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM myfeilds");
$statement->execute();
$results=$statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$json=json_encode($results);
```

How can I do this ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'server.php',
        success : //........
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass an array using PHP & Ajax to Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263052/how-to-pass-an-array-using-php-ajax-to-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to echo the something in server side to return the ajax

**PHP:**

```
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Contact', 'root', '');
    $statement=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM myfeilds");
    $statement->execute();
    $results=$statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $json=json_encode($results);
     echo $json;

    ?>
```

**Ajax :**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'server.php',
        dataType:"json",
        success : function (data) {

            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
           }
        }
      }); 
    });
```

Comment: thanks ...How can I print it on the table or div ? This means that for each variable in a special section can  print

Comment: take look at here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189365/use-jquery-to-convert-json-array-to-html-bulleted-list @Toprex

Answer (score 1):

Ok so you seem to have got enough downvotes but I am also guessing you're fairly new so here's my little help:

PHP:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Contact', 'root', '');
$statement=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM myfeilds");
$statement->execute();
$results=$statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$json=json_encode($results);

return $json; // Return this back to your browser
?>
```

Javascript / jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : 'server.php',
    dataType:"json",
    success : function (data) {
       for ( var d in data ) {
          var column1 = data[d].column1;
       }
    }
  }); 
});
```

You might want to have a look at the [documentation on ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)...